# How to configure spark cluster (memory, core, executor) based on input data/file size?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, bigdata, databricks

There are formulas available to determine Spark job "Executor memory" and "number of Executor" and "executor cores" based on your cluster available Resources, is there any formula available to calculate the same alone with Data size.

```
case 1: what is the configuration if: data size < 5 GB
case 2: what is the configuration if: 5 GB > data size < 10 GB
case 3: what is the configuration if: 10 GB > data size < 15 GB
case 4: what is the configuration if: 15 GB > data size < 25 GB
case 5: what is the configuration if: data size < 25 GB
```

Tried finding this from multiple source but didn't get any proper explanation.

Answer (score 0):

First element that should guide you to choosing the correct amount of resources is not necessarily the size of data but rather the number of **partitions** - the general rule of thumb is that optimal number of partitions should be equal or bigger than number of cores in your executors - you can read more about it in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52412679/what-is-a-good-number-of-partitions-in-spark-as-a-function-of-number-of-executor) thread.

Second thing is if you will be **caching** your DataFrames explicitly (`cache` method) - in this case the amount of RAM should also be sufficient to store all the data inside it (otherwise the data will spill into the storage, which kills the benefits of caching). [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22734849/apache-spark-memory-consumption-for-cache-persist) related to this topic.

Comment: Thanks much Bartosz.. will go thru the links for better understsnding..

Comment: No problem - these might be difficult topics, so don't get discouraged at first read :)